# Passing a mysql query to the database using a java program

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I am new to mysql and I am trying to connect to the database using a Java Program and I am passing a mysql query.

```
public class dbconnect {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?user=root&password=root");
        Statement st =  conn.createStatement();


        int custid= 0;
            String myname = null;
        String query = "select name from groups where customer_id = 2;"; 
        //This query has a problem can anyone help me fix it.
            System.out.println(query);
            ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(query);

            System.out.println("after query");
            while (rs1.next()){
                 custid = rs1.getInt("customer_id");
                 myname = rs1.getString("name");

                System.out.println(myname);
                System.out.println(custid);
            }
    }
}
```

I am passing a query "select name from groups where customer_id = 2" .
Here "name" is a coloumn,"groups" is a table and "customer_id" is another column. In the program when I give this query(no typos) I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column 'customer_id' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2815)
    at com.memoir.client.widgets.memogen.dbconnect.main(dbconnect.java:61)
```

I have checked with the table , customer_id is present in the table . They are no spelling mistakes also .Even then it says that customer_id column is not found .
Can anyone help me fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query needs to be:

```
String query = "select name, customer_id from groups where customer_id = 2;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it doesn't make any sense, your query is

```
    String query = "select name from groups where customer_id = 2;";
```

and you expect to get customer_id ??

as you are already passing customer_id in where clause you don't need to get it back again from db.

```
    String query = "select customer_id,name from groups where customer_id = 2;";
```

The above would work with your current code .

Comment: Thanks, I am new to mysql . Sorry about that missed it

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing only **name**  column in query and you are try to get "**customer_id**" in while loop from result set

```
     while (rs1.next()){
                 custid = rs1.getInt("customer_id"); // **error is here - remove this line or  change your query**
                 myname = rs1.getString("name");

                System.out.println(myname);
                System.out.println(custid);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to get an invalid column ("cutomer_id") from the result set which contains only the "name" column.

To resolve this you have to select also the "customer_id" in your query:

```
"select name, customer_id from groups where customer_id = 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 custid = rs1.getInt("customer_id");
```

you result set does not have customer_id

Include that too in your query

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String mysqlquery = "select name, customer_id from groups where customer_id=2";
```